# Importing googlesheets into pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, google-sheets, pyspark

I'm new to spark and my goal is to get info from a google sheet to a pyspark dataframe.

From what I've seen there is this library https://github.com/potix2/spark-google-spreadsheets

However, from what I understand, since it's a scala library is for "regular" spark only.
What I'd like to do would be to load the google sheet info into a pyspark dataframe, without needing to download it. I'd also would like to avoid using pandas to load it and then send it to a pyspark dataframe.

I have this code so far. I know it won't work, but I can't figure out if is possible to use the mentioned library or if I have to take another approach.

```
 import pyspark
 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

SparkSession.builder.appName('Practise').config("spark.executorENV.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS","home/pathtocreds.json").getOrCreate()
    df = spark.read.load("gsheetid/worksheet0")
    df.show()
```

Thank you for your help.